# Setting default from address of email in ios

Tags: ios, email

In my app, there is an email functionality which should send email from an id, which is not configured with mail app. From address will be like noreplyATgmail.com .. some thing like that.

How can I hard code the from address of an email ?

Comment: You can't, you should use `reply-to` for that, or get a server to send the email. The `from` gets set from the selected email address you chose to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to send email from account where user isn't authorised in.
For your aims it's better implement email functionality on server side that could be authorised to send emails from address that you specified.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment - you can't, you should use `reply-to` for that, or send a request to a server to send the email. The `from` gets set from the selected email address you eventually chose to send the email with.

For example:

```
mailto:email@email.com?subject=Subject&reply-to=noreply@something.com
```

I don't think there's anyway to do this using [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).